# SQL SELECT from Excel on local database is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, select

I have an Excel file where in one column I have thousands of SELECT COUNT(*) statements to execute on SQL Server.  I would like to execute all SELECT statements in column A and have the result populated in column B

```
A                                                      B
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE <condition 1>       5
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE <condition 2>       0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE <condition 3>       2
```

I managed to write the following code (am new to ADO) and it works but it is VERY SLOW executing each SELECT COUNT(*) in ~ 2.5 seconds!  The SQL database is local.  Is there anything I can do to significantly improve the speed as I have over 500,000 such queries to run.  Alternatively, I am considering importing the queries from Excel to a SQL table and run a SQL script to do a similar task but I have no experience with SQL scripts so hoping for a fix on my VBA script. Thanks!

```
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rsPubs
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A100:A500")
    For Each cell In rng
        sqlstmt = cell.Value
        .Open sqlstmt
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Fields(0).Value
        .Close
    Next
End With
```

Comment: You can do this using ADO - plenty of examples to be found via Google.  Eg: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306125

Comment: Maybe you need to add some indexes? Hard to say without seeing exactly what your `WHERE` clauses look like. If you're just querying the counts on individual values in a particular column then a single query with `group by colName` would be more efficient.

Comment: Tim, your hint about the indexes was spot on. My queries were all on the same 2 columns so I created 2 indexes for these columns and now it is very fast! Thanks very much!